# Laravel Jobs: Assumed index "job" causing error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, amazon-sqs

I've got a Laravel 5.7 app consuming an SQS queue, populated by an external app to trigger some basic integration tasks.

I'm seeing in my Laravel logs this error:

```
Undefined index: job at (proj-dir)/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php:234
```

I can see the Jobs class is assuming a "job" index - but you can't assume that is set... unless the Laravel implementation assumes reading and writing to the SQS queue is handled only by Laravel.

```
/**
 * Get the name of the queued job class.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->payload()['job'];
}
```

I'm surprised this hasn't been reported all over the place. Perhaps I'm using it differently than most.

I'm not sure if I need to ask the other provider to specify a job name in the payload, or modify the Laravel core to not assume this is required.

Comment: Did you find any solution of this?

Comment: I got such error, In my case, the problem was I'd updated the code without restarting the workers.

Comment: Hi @JamesNZ did you find solution on this?